# How to mix MP3's using LAME

Tags: audio, mp3, encoding, c, lame

I have N MP3 files (N files for example). I need to superimpose, or mix them into one. Is there a special [LAME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAME) function for performing such an operation?

Comment: Is this programming related?

Comment: @dtb - yea. LAME is a library.

Comment: Do you want to reencode them or to splice the channels mono -> stereo?

Comment: "How do I do $FOO using tool N" is presupposing part of your answer if what you really want to know is "How do I do $FOO"; sometimes, tool N isn't the right thing for the job. "How do I do $FOO on platform N", or "How do I do $FOO in a manner compatible with N" are better questions.

Answer (score 3):

LAME is the wrong tool for mixing -- mixing isn't encoding.

Do the mixing with a tool such as [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/), then encode the mixed stream with LAME.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) to mix them, and Audacity will then use the LAME encoder to encode the mixed audio as MP3.